# How to use sequelize iLike with substring

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to make a query like %hat%. While doing this, it should not be case sensitive.

iLike only works as %hat.

My Code;

```
exports.list = async (where, page = 0, size = 50, search) => {
    return thisModel.findAll({
        where: {
            parentId: where.parentId,
            name: {
                [Op.substring]: search
            }
        },
        raw: true,
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        offset: page * size,
        limit: size,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, maybe not good. Working :)

```
[Op.iLike]: `${search}%`
```